# Automatically connect to samba with changing ip address

Tags: networking, network-shares, samba

I have a Ubuntu system I am sharing a drive to my windows with. It works fine except that whenever the ip changes, on Windows I have to delete the share and create a new one with the new ip.

There must be a way around this?

anyway to do it without static ip? I'm at a work machine and it's a dynamic ip

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is! What you need to do is to set up a static IP address on the Linux machine that is serving the share.

To do this you will need access to the router. Depending on the brand of the router you can access it via a web browser by navigating to its IP address. In many cases the address is **192.168.1.1** or similar, you will have to look up the default address for your router to find out. Also this information is sometimes available on a sticker on the routing device itself.

Every router configuration is a little different but generally what you need to do is follow the instructions for setting a static IP address which you'll find in the manual for your device (probably online).

If you have access to the router and you have some idea about configuring it you can go into the settings and look under **LAN** or **local network** or similar and find a list of connected devices. In this list should be your Linux machine (you can usually tell by the hostname).

Once you have found the Linux machine in the list you need to make sure that the mac address matches the mac address of the Linux machine you use for the share (you can find this address with the command: ifconfig). Once you have confirmed the mac address you must set up a static IP address for that machine's specific mac address.

The area in your router settings to set static IPs is always different so if it is not obvious you'll have to look it up. In my experience it is usually somewhere around the **DHCP** settings which is usually under **LAN**.

Once that's finished your Linux machine will always have the same address and your share should work fine.

Good Luck!

Comment: anyway to do it without static ip? I'm at a work machine and it's a dynamic ip. I was in the process of coming back to edit my post because I knew you would give this answer! Sorry! I thumbed up your post though.